# find a pattern on string

Tags: c#

I am giving you an example for what I am exactly want.

Example string:

> If you're on a work BES system (work issued BlackBerry most likely with a BlackBerry server) then the "www.blackberry.com" BlackBerry follows the Exchange servers rules (aka if outlook redirects your email to a folder, then so does BlackBerry). However, there is an email option that you tell your BlackBerry not to show messages in other folders other than Inbox.

A web link is inside this paragraph. How can I find this Weblink (www.blackberry.com) from this paragraph in my C# application.and 
i want to find it any type of string

Comment: Do you want to find any web link in any paragraph, or specifically www.blackberry.com in this specific paragraph?

Answer (score 3):

You're talking about finding any hyperlink in a block of text with a regular expression? Jeff Atwood [wrote about this](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-urls/) a while back. Although in the end he uses a little bit more than just a pure regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class to search for patterns.  There is a [tutorial on DevHood.com](http://devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=523) that goes into regular expression matching in some detail, with C# examples.